# Tree layout printing software for continuous sheet paper

Tags: software-recommendations, chart-type

Is there any software other than Swift Family tree that will print to a continuous sheet (banner paper)?

I find trying to fit many sheets on to a small desk hard to follow.

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy.SE! Most any modern commercial package will be able to do this. Do you have any other criteria for the software? It would make it easier to answer if there were more specific criteria provided. However, again, welcome to Genealogy.SE!

Comment: Swift Family Ancestry (Software) by Cosmi / Platform: Windows 95 

http://www.amazon.com/Swift-Family-Ancestry/dp/B000L6W33U

http://archiver.rootsweb.ancestry.com/th/read/GEN-MAT-UKI/2006-07/1152712895

Comment: Tony, Do you have a printer that uses continuous sheets? ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_stationery )

Comment: If you do then Brothers Keeper software should be able to print to Banner paper (continuously) http://www.bkwin.org

Answer (score 4):

So long as you have a printer that will accept continuous paper (either in a roll or fanfold), then many software packages will allow you to define a custom paper size that is as large as you need.

Here is the dialogue in GRAMPS where I create a 10 metre long sheet of what is (in effect) continuous A4.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option you have is to print at a local office supply store (eg Staples if in US). They generally have options to print up to 3 feet wide by any length. Most genealogy software allowed printing on custom sized sheets (or will auto-determine the best size for a given tree). I personally use 3'x3's for fan charts and have varying sizes for trees with 5'x2' the biggest I happen to have hanging at moment. I find the copy shop's 'wider' printer better than continuous roll. You can also do mailaway (ie they mail it to you) but that tends to be more expensive.